# Is fosrestbundle compatible with symfony 4/4.1?

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony4

I didn't found any **official** information about FOSRestBundle compatibility with Symfony 4 and Symfony 4.1. Do you know something about it? I only found information from 2017, so I guess they can be not updated..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, latest version are compatible with symfony 4, look at those links:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/1847

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/releases

Inside the issue, the maintainer, answer that is compatible.

Into release 2.3.1 there is mention about symfony4 so, yes you could use symfony 4 and fosRestBundle

Comment: Comment apart, not an answer: what symfony team recommends now is to use Api Platform. :)

Comment: @MatíasNavarroCarter I'm not sure of this because Api Platform isn't always a solution, I always recommend FosRestBundle with a custom syste, created by the team, but it's a point of view IMHO :)

Comment: I'm not stating that FOSRest is not a valid solution. My statement just was that Symfony now officially recommends ApiPlatform, since it is in their official list of curated bundle recipes. Also, it is developed by a Core Team Member. Also, Fabien [has used it](https://medium.com/@fabpot/symfony-4-a-small-screencast-cf6511823f). And finally, some Symfony core members (and I share their opinion) have said that it is too broad a package [here](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/158).

But again, not questioning that can be a valid solution.

Comment: Sure @MatíasNavarroCarter but ApiPlatform uses graphql so the first is: do you really need graphql? In many projects no because is another architecture another way to make project, many core members are contributing con ApiPlatform but remember that is better to have your system to have more control on your code and application :)

Comment: What you say is partially false: Api Platform **supports** GraphQL, but you can literally disable/enable every single feature. For example, I have a project now that does not have swagger docs, nor swagger ui, nor graph ql. And is so simple like to write a boolean value in a config file. Moreover, I don't think graphql comes enabled by default.